# python default context object ssl

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to establish a connection using ssl in python (I'm using python 3.6.1).
I'm very new to ssl and so I read the ssl documentation and I saw that there is a function called create_default_context that return a new SSLContext object with default setting and I did'nt fully understand this function.
I want to create a ssl server (client is in javascript). 
My question is if I can use only the default context that I'm creating or do I need to create self signed certificate and key file for the server as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The cert file verification can be ignored by setting the `verfiy_mode` to `CERT_NONE` (default mode in Python 3.6, `ssl` module). In this mode, only encryption of data is proceeded, the identity of the server and the client will not be veried. Be careful that this is unsecure.

Comment: So if i set the verify_mode to cert_none i should be able to use the default context object without creating self signed certificate ?

Comment: The `verify_mode` determines how to treat the certificate of the other side. If you simply want not to load cert file at server side, you can directly use `ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.xxx)` and use the context instance to wrap a socket instance. That's enough.